# Minor and Major Axis Android Devices

Tags: android, android-xml, axis

What are the major and minor axis in android devices ? How can I define which axis is major and minor **at the runtime** ?
If application is bound to be "portrait" via Manifest will it affect major/minor axis?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

> Definition of the coordinate system used by the SensorEvent API.
>
> The coordinate-system is defined relative to the screen of the phone
> in its default orientation. The axes are not swapped when the device's
> screen orientation changes.
>
> The X axis is horizontal and points to the right, the Y axis is vertical and points up and the Z axis points towards the outside of the front face of the screen. In this system, coordinates behind the screen have negative Z values.

Definition from [android developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html)

Comment: I know that, the question is what is MAJOR ad MINOR ?